# Automation of application testing

Tags: testing, automation

I need to fire up an application acting as a web server and wireshark, wait for a connection, exchange data, take screenshot of the web server application and wireshark debug window, and close both applications. I need to repeat this every hour.

What are the best programs for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look AutoIt: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml

Comment: good tip, simple to use; the only downside is it isn't compile checked.